# How to make use of Radio Group with useFormik Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to get useFormik to validate radio groups, but it seems not to work, here is a brief example of what I am doing, whenever I submit the form after checking any of the radio input, formik throws validation error, ({currState:"you must choose property state"}), even though I choose an option.
I realized getFieldProps attaches value field to the radio, so i tried using defaultValue then react throws an error about choosing one of controlled and uncontrolled components.

```
     import { useFormik } from "formik"
     export function ListProperty(){
     const { handleSubmit, getFieldProps, touched, errors } = useFormik(
             {
           initialValues: {
            currState:"",
          },
      validationSchema:Yup.object().shape({
         currState:Yup.string().required("you must choose property state")
     }),
     return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >

         <div className="form-group inline">
            <div className="form-control">
              <input type="radio" 
              name="currState"  
              {...getFieldProps("currState")} 
              value="serviced" 
              />
              <label>serviced</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-control">
              <input 
              type="radio" 
              value="furnished" 
              name="currState"  
              {...getFieldProps("currState")} 
              />
              <label>furnished</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-control">
              <input
                type="radio"
                value="newlybuilt"
               name="currState"  
              {...getFieldProps("currState")} 
              />
              <label>newly built</label>
            </div>

          </div>
           <button type="submit">submit </button>
           </form>
     )
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I gave up on the implementation with `getFieldProps` and did it simpler, like this:

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik'

export default function Component() {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { 
      radioButtonValue: ''
    },
    onSubmit: values => console.log(values)
  })

  const handleRadioButtons = e => formik.values.radioButtonValue = e.target.value

  return (
   <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
     <input 
       type="radio" 
       id="one"
       name="group" 
       value="One" 
       onChange={e => handleRadioButtons(e)}
       required
     />
     <label htmlFor="one">One</label>
     <br />

     <input 
       type="radio" 
       id="two"
       name="group" 
       value="Two" 
       onChange={e => handleRadioButtons(e)}
     />
     <label htmlFor="two">Two</label>

     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  )
}
```

Beware, if you use `formik.values.radioButtonValue` value as a useEffect dependency, then setting it like this: `formik.values.radioButtonValue = e.target.value` not gonna trigger the change, and useEffect won't launch (at least in my case it didn't). As an alternative, you gonna have to implement some kind of condition check with this value in your useEffect code

Answer (score 1):

You need to map onChange like below.

```
<input 
  type="radio" 
  value="furnished" 
  name="currState"  
  onChange={getFieldProps("currState").onChange} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my form that's work:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="number" value="one" onChange={formik.getFieldProps("number").onChange}/>One
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="two" onChange{formik.getFieldProps("number").onChange}/>Two
</label>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
const formik = useFormik(
    {
        initialValues: {
            projectActivity: "Active"
        },
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            console.log(values);
        }
    }
);

<div className='flex flex-col'>
                    <label className='font-bold ml-1 my-1'>Project Activity</label>
                    <div className='flex justify-start items-center gap-x-3 mt-1'>
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="projectActivity"
                            id="active"
                            value="Active"
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            checked={formik.values.projectActivity === 'Active'}
                            className="radio"
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="active">Active</label>
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="projectActivity"
                            id="inactive"
                            value="Inactive"
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            checked={formik.values.projectActivity === 'Inactive'}
                            className="radio"
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="inactive">Inactive</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).